# How to implement model-to-image registration in SimpleITK?

Tags: image, itk, simpleitk

I installed SimpleITK for medical image registration. It works very well for 3D CT/CT and 3D CT/MRI image registration. Now I want to implement model/image registration. The model is a sphere. In ITK there are Spatial Objects like Box, Ellipse which can be used for model/image registration. But I can't find those objects in SimpleITK.  Should I create a fake image from the model and use image/image registration to simulate the model/image registration?

Thanks,

David Lau

Answer (score 0):

Converting spatial object to an image, and then using image-to-image registration is certainly one solution. Registration precision will somewhat depend on the resolution of the image grid for converting `SpatialObject`->`Image`. Same pixel spacing as the other image is a reasonable choice.

Comment: Thanks Dzenan. Your answer is very helpful. Is there any filter in SimpleITK which can convert SpatialObject to Image? There are some filters in ITK which can do that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleITK currently does not have support for spacial objects, or spacial object registration. The last time I did spatial object to image registration it was rather slow and I ended up "rendering" the spacial object to an image to perform image to image registration. There are several C++ ITK examples (SpatialObjectToImage[0-3].cxx) which could be adopted to generate this image.

Alternatively in SimpleITK there is the [PhysicalPointImageSource](https://itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1PhysicalPointImageSource.html), which generate a image of points. Then using overloaded operators, and the equation of a sphere or hyper-ellipse can be used to generate an approximation to the implicit object desired. [Here](http://insightsoftwareconsortium.github.io/SimpleITK-Notebooks/20_Expand_With_Interpolators.html) is an example of the Marschner Lobb function being generated:

```
def marschner_lobb(size=40, alpha=0.25, f_M=6.0):
  img = sitk.PhysicalPointSource( sitk.sitkVectorFloat32, [size]*3, [-1]*3, [2.0/size]*3)
  imgx = sitk.VectorIndexSelectionCast(img, 0)
  imgy = sitk.VectorIndexSelectionCast(img, 1)
  imgz = sitk.VectorIndexSelectionCast(img, 2)
  del img
  r = sitk.Sqrt(imgx**2 + imgy**2)
  del imgx, imgy
  pr = sitk.Cos((2.0*math.pi*f_M)*sitk.Cos((math.pi/2.0)*r))
  return (1.0 - sitk.Sin((math.pi/2.0)*imgz) + alpha*(1.0+pr))/(2.0*(1.0+alpha))
```

A similar operation can be done for other implicit functions.